# Bootstrap css - div height and overflowing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my friend's website which I can't solve. If you could help I'd be very pleased..
And the problem is:

My bootstrap div doesn't hold a height and is going under following div, especially in tablet/phone responsive version. Maybe it will be easier if I give you the address:

http://trido.io/index3.html

and the code I'm talking about is:

```
    <section id="download" class="download bg-primary text-center">
   <div class="container">


            <div class='col-md-1'>
               <!-- <img src="img/gify/pionNew.gif" alt="" align="center" /> -->
            </div>


        <div class='col-md-4'>

            <div class="row">

                 <div class='col-md-1'>
                </div>


                 <div class='col-md-9'>

                    <p align="center">TriDo - Do a chain of three!</p><br>
                    <p>Arrange your balls in order from 1 to 3:
                    horizontally, vertically or diagonally. Prevent opponent's arrangement of balls.</p><br><br>
                </div>
           </div>


           <div class="row">

                <ul>
                    <li>Multiplayer<li>
                    <li>Endless single-player mode<li>
                    <li>Game Center leaderboards<li>
                    <li>Game Center Achievements<li>
                </ul>



           </div>


         </div>

        <div class='col-md-1'>

         </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">

               <div class="device-container">
                    <div class="device-mockup iphone6 portrait black">
                        <div class="device">
                            <div class="screen">

                                       <!--  <video width="300" height="534" controls> -->
                                             <video width="270" height="480" controls>

                                            <source src="TrailerDoTel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                            <source src="TrailerDoTel.ogg" type="video/ogg">

                                            </video> 

                                <div class="button"> 
                                </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> 
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-0.5'>
               <!-- <img src="img/gify/pionNew.gif" alt="" align="center" /> -->
            </div>

      </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `<div class="device-mockup iphone6 portrait black">` is set to position `absolute` which takes the element out of the flow of the document, so its content will not affect other elements in the DOM.

If you set it to `position: relative;` it will no longer overlap the div below it.

Or you can give your `.device-container` a static height, like `height: 676px;`

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much! But..
now my div have strange bottom margin/padding which I can't make smaller... It's unnaturaly big..
Can you help me with that too? Thank you very much :)